# What are all of the ways to decrease the amount of sleep required other than race/class features and the ring of sustenance?

Tags: dnd-5e, sleep

Beyond the class features, racial traits, and feats that reduce the amount of sleep required for a long rest to 4 hours and the ring of sustenance that halves it I can't find any other ways to reduce the amount of time required.

Did I miss anything?

I was hoping to find a way because of a campaign i had an idea for where you would also be put into battles while asleep, so you would want to be able to have less sleep with the same effect to avoid those battles, not just as a way to make sleep less important. If there isn't a way I can homebrew something, but I would prefer to not homebrew anything if there is an existing way.

Comment: Related: "[How can my character avoid having to breathe, eat, drink, or sleep?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/93256)"

Comment: Without knowing what class features, racial traits, and feats you're thinking of, we have no idea whether it's a complete list. In addition, as Medix2 said, you should clarify what you mean by the *ring of sustenance*; the [*ioun stone* (sustenance)](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/ioun-stone-of-sustenance) exists, but it doesn't affect sleep in any way.

Comment: @Medix2 Some races like elves have a trait that lets them sleep for only 4 hours instead of 8 for a long rest, as well as others like warforged not needing to sleep at all. The ring of sustenance is a magic ring that requires attunement that removes your need for food or water and halves the amount of sleep required in a long rest. There is also a feat called light sleeper that has the same effect as racial traits like chance where it reduces the time required from 8 hours to 4.

Comment: @JackKuni Ah, just so you know, the [Ring of Sustenance](https://www.5esrd.com/gamemastering/magic-items/magic-items-by-other-publishers/magic-items-frog-god-games/ring-of-sustenance) is not a WotC-published item; it is from Frog God Games and is not official for 5e. Similarly, the [Light Sleeper feat](https://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/Light_Sleeper_\(5e_Feat\)) is homebrew material and is not official. To that end, there is likely *plenty* of non-official content that does what you want, but I assume you are only interested in *official* published materials?

Comment: Ok then. I had thought that both were official. I would prefer official methods, but if there aren't any im not opposed to homebrew or unofficial content.

Comment: Is your 'goal' here to have 'dream battles' and you are looking for ways to avoid them for your players? That feels like what your real question is.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After further research, I have figured out that there are no official methods.

However, there are unofficial and homebrew methods that have already been made that I can use, like the [*ring of sustenance*](https://www.5esrd.com/gamemastering/magic-items/magic-items-by-other-publishers/magic-items-frog-god-games/ring-of-sustenance) (*City of Brass*, p. 534) and the [Light Sleeper](https://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/Light_Sleeper_(5e_Feat)) feat (from dandwiki).

Comment: Relevant to the latter: [Why does dandwiki have a poor reputation?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/109306/33569)

Answer (score 3):

The only one I know of is the Warlock Aspect of the Moon Invocation from XGtE, which makes it so you do not need to sleep.

> You no longer need to sleep and can’t be forced to sleep by any means. To gain the benefits of a long rest, you can spend all 8 hours doing light activity.

Keep in mind that long rests are a large part of D&D 5e and making them shorter is very powerful.

Comment: I was hoping to find a way because of a campaign i had an idea for where you would also be put into battles while asleep, so you would want to be able to have less sleep with the same effect to avoid those battles.

Comment: @JackKuni Please add that to the question, along with the other requested clarifications :)

Comment: @JackKuni keep in mind if you are running a campaign, as the DM, you could always Homebrew a magic item to do this, especially if the game is centered around it